# Execute a script with GUI Access before login

Tags: macos, launchd, startup

I need to execute a command-line tool to force maximum display brightness before user logs in (so login screen is shown with maximum brightness)

My problem is, if I run it from `LaunchDaemons`, it doesn't work. I think it is because from `LaunchDaemons` you can't run anything that interacts with the Window Server.

If I run it from `LaunchAgents`, it works. But it runs after login, so it is not an option.

Is there any alternative to `LaunchDaemons` to run scripts or programs that allow WindowServer access?

Comment: Do you need to run a specific brightness tool – or will a general Mac display brightness tool work? See [mac display brightness](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=mac%20display%20brightness) at GitHub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## PreLoginAgents

macOS supports the ability to run graphical applications pre-login:

> ## [Running Agents Before Login](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW10-SW2)
>
> Most software that displays a user interface does not run prior to the user logging in. However, in some rare cases, it may be necessary to create a graphical agent that does.
>
> By default, OS X does not allow any application to draw content prior to login. If you need to do so, your agent must call the [`setCanBecomeVisibleWithoutLogin:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419179-canbecomevisiblewithoutlogin) method on its windows. For more information, see the documentation for that method and the [PreLoginAgents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PreLoginAgents/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004414) sample code.

The trick is to add the following lines to your /Library/LaunchAgents  launchd plist:

```
<key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
<string>LoginWindow</string>
```

The executable must be stored in `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools`.

We used this ability to show a notification window pre-login for [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager) pending events.

This functionality may not be supported in the latest macOS; we have not relied on it for a long while.

Comment: It works !!!! I followed the coding example in the link you provided and I was missing 2 things: 1) PLIST in LaunchAgents vs LaunchDaemons, and 2) executable in /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools .

Comment: Great to hear you have it working. I have updated the answer to mention the LaunchAgents and helper tools folders.